# PostgreSQL: left outer join syntax

Tags: postgresql, left-join, outer-join

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.6 with CentOS 5.5 and have a table of users:

```
# select * from pref_users where id='DE2';
 id  | first_name | last_name | female |      avatar      |        city         | lat | lng |           login            | last_ip | medals |           logout
-----+------------+-----------+--------+------------------+---------------------+-----+-----+----------------------------+---------+--------+----------------------------
 DE2 | Alex       |           | f      | 2_1280837766.jpg | г. Бохум в Германии |     |     | 2011-01-02 19:26:37.790909 |         |        | 2011-01-02 19:29:30.197062
(1 row)
```

and another table listing their "virtual money" won in a game each week:

```
# select * from pref_money where id='DE2';
 id  | money |   yw
-----+-------+---------
 DE2 |    66 | 2010-48
(1 row)
```

Then I'm trying to display both of these infos for a user, but I'm only interested in the user's money for the current week:

```
# select u.id,
    u.first_name,
    u.city,
    u.avatar,
    m.money,
    u.login > u.logout as online
from pref_users u, pref_money m where
    m.yw=to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-IW') and
    u.id=m.id and
    u.id='DE2'
order by m.money desc;
 id | first_name | city | avatar | money | online
----+------------+------+--------+-------+--------
(0 rows)
```

In this case I've got no rows, because the user 'DE2' hasn't earned any "virtual money" this week yet.

I'd like to change my query so that it **always returns data for existing users** and if they haven't played this week - then the query should return 0.

So I guess I need an [outer left join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) and I'm trying:

```
 select u.id,
    u.first_name,
    u.city,
    u.avatar,
    m.money,
    u.login > u.logout as online
from pref_users u left outer join pref_money m on (
    m.yw=to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-IW') and
    u.id=m.id and
    u.id='DE2')
order by m.money desc;
```

but these returns me a lot of rows with different users instead of just one with the id='DE2'.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select u.id,
       u.first_name,
       u.city,
       u.avatar,
       coalesce(m.money,0),
       u.login > u.logout as online
  from pref_users u left outer join pref_money m on u.id=m.id
       and m.yw=to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-IW') 
 where u.id='DE2'
 order by m.money desc;
```

Comment: EDIT: added the m.yw back into the on-clause

Answer (score 1):

You want to put the filter condition `u.id='DE2'` in the WHERE clause, leaving everything else in the ON clause. For every user where the ON doesn't match, it will still output the row with the data from *u* and nulls for *m*.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the

```
u.id='DE2'
```

into a WHERE clause, like this:

```
select u.id,
    u.first_name,
    u.city,
    u.avatar,
    m.money,
    u.login > u.logout as online
from pref_users u left outer join pref_money m on u.id=m.id
where m.yw=to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-IW') and
    u.id='DE2'
order by m.money desc;
```